# Rotation of matrices with complex eigenvalues and complex eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, rotations

Why is it $|\lambda|^2$? Isn't the rotation determined by just $|\lambda|$?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The square of the absolute value is easier to calculate—no need to do the square rooting. Also, $1$ is the only nonnegative number whose square is $1$, so this is enough to determine that $|\lambda|=1$.

Comment: So in all cases, $|\lambda|^2=|\lambda|$?

Comment: $|\lambda|=1 \iff |\lambda|^2 = 1$ is the relevant implication.